# Perl dereferencing in non-strict mode

Tags: perl, dereference, perldoc, perlop

In Perl, if I have:

```
no strict;
@ARY = (58, 90);
```

To operate on an element of the array, say it, the 2nd one, I would write (possibly as part of a larger expression):

```
$ARY[1]  # The most common way found in Perldoc's idioms.
```

Though, for some reason these also work:

```
@ARY[1]
@{ARY[1]}
```

Resulting all in the same object:

```
print (\$ARY[1]);
print (\@ARY[1]);
print (\@{ARY[1]});
```

Output:

```
SCALAR(0x9dbcdc)
SCALAR(0x9dbcdc)
SCALAR(0x9dbcdc)
```

What is the syntax rules that enable this sort of constructs? How far could one devise reliable program code with each of these constructs, or with a mix of all of them either? How interchangeable are these expressions? (always speaking in a non-strict context).

On a concern of justifying how I come into this question, I agree "use strict" as a better practice, still I'm interested at some knowledge on build-up non-strict expressions.

In an attemp to find myself some help to this uneasiness, I came to:

- The notion on "no strict;" of not complaining about undeclared
  variables and quirk syntax.
- The prefix dereference having higher precedence than subindex [] (perldsc § "Caveat on precedence").
- The clarification on when to use @ instead of $ (perldata § "Slices").
- The lack of "[]" (array subscript / slice) description among the Perl's operators (perlop), which lead me to think it is not an
  operator... (yet it has to be something else. But, what?).

For what I learned, none of these hints, put together, make me better understand my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO, the _knowledge_ for `strict` and `no strict` - is the same. The difference is only than the `strict` will help you write correct programs. Switch off the strict only when really needed. (in rare cases, partially, such `no strict 'refs'`; and such.)

Comment: This isn't anything to do with dereferencing, nor anything to do with strict, as far as I can tell, and strict doesn't know or care about "quirk syntax".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotation from perlfaq4:

> #### What is the difference between `$array[1]` and `@array[1]`?
>
> The difference is the sigil, that special character in front of the array name. The `$` sigil means "exactly one item", while the `@` sigil means "zero or more items". The `$` gets you a single scalar, while the `@` gets you a list.

Please see: [What is the difference between $array[1] and @array[1]?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-$array%5B1%5D-and-@array%5B1%5D?)

Answer (score 2):

`@ARY[1]` is indeed a slice, in fact a slice of only one member. The difference is it creates a list context:

```
@ar1[0] = qw( a b c );    # List context.
$ar2[0] = qw( a b c );    # Scalar context, the last value is returned.
print "<@ar1> <@ar2>\n";
```

Output:

```
<a> <c>
```

Besides using `strict`, turn `warnings` on, too. You'll get the following warning:

```
Scalar value @ar1[0] better written as $ar1[0]
```

In perlop, you can read that "Perl's prefix dereferencing operators are typed: $, @, %, and &." The standard syntax is `SIGIL { ... }`, but in the simple cases, the curly braces can be omitted.

See [Can you use string as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1065867) for some fun with `no strict refs` and its emulation under strict.

Answer (score 1):

Extending [choroba's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25733838/970195) answer, to check a particular context, you can use [wantarray](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html)

```
sub context { return wantarray ? "LIST" : "SCALAR" }

print $ary1[0] = context(), "\n";
print @ary1[0] = context(), "\n";
```

#### Outputs:

```
SCALAR
LIST
```

Comment: If you like `wantarray()` you may find `Contextual::Return` of interest, as it lets you detect more nuanced conditions http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Contextual-Return-0.004007/lib/Contextual/Return.pm

Comment: @Sobrique. Looks pretty interesting. Thanks for sharing. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you did requires `no strict;` other than to hide your error of doing

```
@ARY = (58, 90);
```

when you should have done

```
my @ARY = (58, 90);
```

---

The following returns a single element of the array. Since `EXPR` is to return a single index, it is evaluated in scalar context.

```
$array[EXPR]
```

e.g.

```
my @array = qw( a b c d );
my $index = 2;
my $ele = $array[$index];   # my $ele = 'c';
```

---

The following returns the elements identified by `LIST`. Since `LIST` is to return 0 or more elements, it must be evaluated in list context.

```
@array[LIST]
```

e.g.

```
my @array = qw( a b c d );
my @indexes ( 1, 2 );
my @slice = $array[@indexes];   # my @slice = qw( b c );
```

---

```
\( $ARY[$index]   )  # Returns a ref to the element returned by $ARY[$index]
\( @ARY[@indexes] )  # Returns refs to each element returned by @ARY[@indexes]
```

---

```
${foo}       # Weird way of writing $foo. Useful in literals, e.g. "${foo}bar"
@{foo}       # Weird way of writing @foo. Useful in literals, e.g. "@{foo}bar"
${foo}[...]  # Weird way of writing $foo[...].
```

Most people don't even know you can use these outside of string literals.